# python3.7 - NameError: name 'paul' is not defined using

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

```
tekst = input("Enter your word: ")
for i in len(tekst):    
if tekst(i) == tekst(-i):        
print(tekst + " is a palindrome word")    
else:        
print( tekst + " is not a palindrome word")
```

Having some trouble with the input, I am using python 3.7.

Comment: please, edit your code properly

Answer (score 0):

you are using `()` instead of `[]` to access the string characters.
tekst(i) would mean that you are calling a function named tekst and passing i to it, where as tekst[i] is used to address specific element in array.

so this

```
if tekst(i) == tekst(-i):
```

should be

```
 if tekst[i] == tekst[-i]:
```

another way to check for palindrome is

```
if (tekst == tekst[::-1]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You just messed up the syntax. The subscript operator is `[]`, which is used to access any element in a list or a string.

`tekst` is a string, the i<sup>th</sup> member of the string can be accessed using `tekst[i]`. Instead, you have used `tekst(i)` which means you are trying to call a function named `tekst`, which does not exist. Hence the `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

So far you can check the below code to correct the syntax. Remember that `indentation for Python` play very important role which has not been correctly used by your code. You have to use here [].

```
tekst = input("Enter your word: ")
for i in range(len(tekst)):    
       if tekst[-i] == tekst[-i]:        
        print(tekst + " is a palindrome word")    
       else:        
        print( tekst + " is not a palindrome word")
```

You can check the live demo here- [**Demo**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1orS9VWE)
To know how to write program for checking if a string is palindrome or not use the link [**here**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-check-string-palindrome-not/)